# How to remove everything in between parenthesis and trailing space from string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I need to remove everything between all of the parenthesis in a string as well as the trailing space before the comma, how can I do this in ruby on rails? I've found out how to do it when the string is always the same but since the value inside the parenthesis isn't always the same all the methods that I've found fail.

The value inside the parenthesis can be `1` to `3` digits so a possible solution has to account for different value lengths.

Sample string:

```
2(2) , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5)
```

Outcome that I want:

```
2, 12, 20, 21
```

I tried using this regex:

```
/(... )
```

Which captures the first 3 matches, but not the last one since it doesn't have a trailing space.

Using only `(...)` causes a match from `2(2) , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5` for some reason.

How can I create a proper regex for this or possibly a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = "2(2) , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5)"
x.gsub(/\(.*?\)/, '')
```

[image]

Comment: The first one only removes the first match, there's a 'g' missing but I can't get it to work when I add it. The second one removes everything except the first digit in the string.

Comment: It also doesn't account for the trailing space

Comment: Doesn't work for me, get the same results as before :/

Comment: 2 , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5) is what it gives

Comment: What about putting your texts into array and to run foreach loop?

Comment: I can't modify it like that, all I get from backend is a string which needs to be modified directly in the template.

Comment: 2 , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5) is what I get at the moment, only the first match.

Comment: my code works perfectly! Look at screen, I've updated my answer

Comment: Ah my bad, I had forgotten the g in front of sub so it wasn't globally matching. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "2(2) , 12(3) , 20(2) , 21(5)"
s.gsub(/\(.*?\) ?/, '')
 => "2, 12, 20, 21"
```

This should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Thisone also worked for me (`s` stands for input-string):

```
ar = s.split(',').each.map { |el| el.strip.match(/(\d*)[^\(]/) }
result = ar.each.map {|el| el[0]}
```

It's a bit huge and not very pretty, but does the job :)